# Keyup function event for space key and invert of backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, indexof, keyup

Having some annoying issues with the `e.which` event function. Whenever I write a simple code of on keyup and check which key is pressed it basically does the wrong thing that I want do to!

http://jsbin.com/axosuz/1/edit

Try that out, if you press backspace before anything else it will append the list of words, same goes for up down left right and multiple shifts. It is quite annoying and trying to think of a fix.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
    var list = ['key', 'keep', 'king', 'kept'];
    if(e.which !== 32){
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).val()) === 0) {
            $('#div').append('<span class="autosuggest">' + list[i] + '&nbsp;</span>');
        } else if (list[i].toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) {
            $('#div').html('');
        }
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: To not show the appending list on the keys that don't start in the word. Like up down left right shift and space backspace etc. I only want them to show if it starts with the character of the word. K or anything like that. This is the last problem in my code that I've been working on so trying to figure that one small bug out

Comment: I meant, what is this code supposed to do?  And what does it have to do with `e.which`, which doesn't appear in your code?

Comment: Yeah I realized that after a while, the real code I have does have it in it, for `if(e.which !== 32){//rest of code}` until I realized that I don't think it's just the e.which ...

Answer (score 1):

If the problem occurs when there is no input, check if there is input.

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EGQ8c/1/)

<sup>(sorry, I can't work with jsbin)</sup>

First, move the value access to  the top of the scope.

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

Then check if value has any characters.  Otherwise we don't need to even do the loop.

```
if (!value.length) return;
```

The finished code:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function () {
    var list = ['key', 'keep', 'king', 'kept'],
        value = $(this).val();

    if (!value.length) return;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === 0) {
            $('#div').append('<span class="autosuggest">' + list[i] + '&nbsp;</span>');
        } else if (list[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1) {
            $('#div').html('');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean... can you provide steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: `if(!value.length) return;` would not give that error.  It most often comes up in an if statement with one `=`, instead of two or three.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience man here is a bin http://jsbin.com/umawog/1/edit  it's not working like it should for some reason, though that's already because the main issue occurs. While in the textarea pressing space and then backspace appends the list. Pressing up down right left and other non essential keys make the list append :x

Comment: Yeah... it doesn't work at all for me.  If [you put my code in](http://jsfiddle.net/UXCS9/), though, it stops that space/backspace problem when its empty.  I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but there's probably a plugin that does it...

Comment: Yeah I don't need a plugin though, this is specific, and shorter than other plugins I found. :D I will try it with your code once more

Comment: yeah it doesn't stop it... press 5 spaces then press backspace a few times it will still append.